# How to pass checkbox values to controller through ajax in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor, checkbox

I have a property in my class which is of string type.

```
public string Months { get; set; }
```

In the view ,I need to create a checkbox list displaying months..
If january is selected 1 should be saved to database.If january and february is selected 1,2 should be saved to database.

I used an ajax form to pass values..It works well for all fields except checkboxlist.

```
 @using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Rate", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccessRateCreate", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "RateForm" }))
    {
    //fields inside this
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Months,new{id="month",value="1"})Jan
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Months,new{id="month1",value="2"})Feb
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Months,new{id="month2",value="3"})Mar
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Months,new{id="month3",value="4"})Apr
    }
```

It shows error:-

```
Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool.
```

Pls help...

Comment: You can not assign same id

Comment: I corrected it..still no change..

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong binding. Try to bind the List of this checkboxes

```
public List<string> Months { get; set; }


 @using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Rate", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccessRateCreate", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "RateForm" }))
    {
 <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="Mounth">    
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Mounth">    
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="Mounth">

    }
```

works for me